# How would I do Cartesian product over nested elements?

Tags: xslt, permutation, self-join, cartesian-product

Given this data:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<data>
    <pricePoint>
        <optionGroup id='g1'>
            <option id='a1'>a1</option>
            <option id='a2'>a2</option>
        </optionGroup>
        <optionGroup id='g2'>
            <option id='b1'>b1</option>
            <option id='b2'>b2</option>
        </optionGroup>
        <optionGroup id='g3'>
            <option id='c1'>c1</option>
            <option id='c2'>c2</option>
        </optionGroup>
    </pricePoint>
</data>
```

The result I'm seeking for is:

```
<result>
    <variant>
        <option id='a1'>a1</option>
        <option id='b1'>b1</option>
        <option id='c1'>c1</option>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <option id='a1'>a1</option>
        <option id='b1'>b1</option>
        <option id='c2'>c2</option>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <option id='a1'>a1</option>
        <option id='b2'>b2</option>
        <option id='c1'>c1</option>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <option id='a1'>a1</option>
        <option id='b2'>b2</option>
        <option id='c2'>c2</option>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <option id='a2'>a2</option>
        <option id='b1'>b1</option>
        <option id='c1'>c1</option>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <option id='a2'>a2</option>
        <option id='b1'>b1</option>
        <option id='c2'>c2</option>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <option id='a2'>a2</option>
        <option id='b2'>b2</option>
        <option id='c1'>c1</option>
    </variant>
    <variant>
        <option id='a2'>a2</option>
        <option id='b2'>b2</option>
        <option id='c2'>c2</option>
    </variant>
</result>
```

That is,

1. Take with the first `<optionGroup>`.
2. For each `<option>` there, traverse all the other `<optionGroup>`s
   and "join" their `<option>`s with the "current" one—producing a single element containing all these `<option>`s in the result document.

The number of `<optionGroup>` elemens in any `<pricePoint>` element is unknown (one or more), and the number of `<option>` elements in any `<optionGroup>` element is unknown, too (one or more).

As far as I understand, this is a classic case of making a Cartesian product but I'm out of ideas on how to implement this properly with XSLT 1.0.

So far my (rather helpless) attempts revolved around the idea of applying the template matching `<optionGroup>` elements while processing one of such elements and trying to exclude it from further processing, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="optionGroup">
        <xsl:message>Saw optionGroup <xsl:value-of select="@id" /></xsl:message>
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../optionGroup[@id != $id]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="option">
        <xsl:message>Saw option</xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sure, all my attemps thus far failed with infinite recursion while applying the templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method, although I am not sure of its efficiency as it has to repeatedly create copies of previous nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pricePoint">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="optionGroup[1]/option" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="optionGroup[following-sibling::*]/option">
        <xsl:param name="previous" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::optionGroup[1]/option">
            <xsl:with-param name="previous">
                <xsl:if test="$previous">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$previous" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="option">
        <xsl:param name="previous" />
        <variant>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$previous" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </variant>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It starts off by selecting the `option` elements under the first `optionGroup`, then recursively calls the template for the `option` elements on the next group, passing the `option` as a parameter, to allow it to build up a list of previous `option` elements.

When it comes to `option` elements under the last `optionGroup` it can output all previous ones, as well as the current one.

EDIT: In response to Martin Honnen's comment, here is a slightly improved way of doing it, that doesn't rely on copies being passed about

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pricePoint">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="optionGroup[1]/option" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="optionGroup[following-sibling::*]/option">
        <xsl:param name="previous" select="/.." />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::optionGroup[1]/option">
            <xsl:with-param name="previous" select="$previous | ." />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="option">
        <xsl:param name="previous" />
        <variant>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$previous" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </variant>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think you need the copies, you can pass the elements on: `    <xsl:template match="optionGroup[following-sibling::*]/option">
        <xsl:param name="previous" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::optionGroup[1]/option">
          <xsl:with-param name="previous" select="$previous | ."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: You are right! I was slightly over-complicating it. I've added a new improved version to my answer, based on your comment. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, @MartinHonnen and Tim! I was starting to think this problem is not really tractable using XSLT alone as it required sort-of backtracking from each element in the "last" set, and I did not know how to implement it. Glad I was wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: I would also shorten `<xsl:copy-of select="$previous" /> <xsl:copy-of select="." />` to `<xsl:copy-of select="$previous | ."/>`.